Downloading a zipped version of a folder
I am trying to download a zipped version of a folder by the name XSLT. This is a code that I've written, however the downloaded xslt.zip file cannot be unzipped. When I use a third party application(7zip), it says there's an error on the headers. What is the workaround for this?
[HttpGet]
[JWTAuthentication]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFiles()
{
    logger.LogTraceStart();

    string folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XSLT");
    string zipPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XSLTlol.zip");

    if (File.Exists(zipPath))
    {
        File.Delete(zipPath);
    }

    try
    {
        // Create the ZIP file
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            // Ensure the directory and files are accessible and not locked
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Directory not found.");
        }

        // Verify the ZIP file was created
        if (!File.Exists(zipPath))
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Failed to create ZIP file.");
        }

        // Create the HTTP response
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

       // result.Content.AddHea

        //result.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "_Templates.Zip");

        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "XSLTlol"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An error occurred while creating the ZIP file.");
    }
    finally
    {
      
        this.session.Flush();
        logger.LogTraceEnd();
    }

}

My ideal output must be a downloadble zip file which can be unzipped and viewed when utilizing the HttpGet API endpoint.

What size is the file that's downloaded?

According to your scenario, ensure proper deletion of any existing ZIP files before creating a new one, use Dispose for the FileStream to guarantee proper resource management, and correctly set the filename property in the Content-Disposition header to include the .zip extension.

@Charlieface it's around 3mb
